# How to create a custom button for the visual editor that adds 4 non-breaking spaces? (plugin or simple code)

Tags: plugins, code

To Wordpress' visual editor (TinyMCE), I would like to add a button that adds four non-breaking spaces when clicked, like this:

```
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
```

I found some plugins that add buttons to the HTML editor, but not to the visual editor ([this one](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/post-editor-buttons-fork/) for e.g).

or in general, it would be nice to know if there's a plugin or a codable (but simple) alternative to add custom buttons to the visual tinyMCE editor.

Comment: do you want to add tiny-mce button??

Comment: @phantom.omaga yes, that's right.

Comment: I hope I'm not out of place asking, but did the comment by @Alexey not work? If so, what was wrong? The reason I ask is I find your question interesting and want to implement something similar, but don't want to waste time trying things willy-nilly if a given answer does not work.

Comment: @AKTed Actually, the last time I tried, I could not get it to work. I wasn't persistent enough then as I had to get things done. Now I am back to get this done. :)

Comment: @its_me How was my answer, did it solve your question?

Comment: @ChristineCooper It worked, very good. I must thank you. I am just waiting (upvotes)... to see which of the two answers deserves the bounty. Please don't mind.

Comment: You are welcome, although I would not rely on the upvote as you are considering of when each answer were posted. I would instead ask you to review the code itself and see which one functions the best for your question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I already demonstrated how you can achieve such thing in this [question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/76976/shortcode-to-insert-nextpage/76989#76989) but I can explain it here again with your request. I have tested this in Wordpress 3.5 and it works elegantly. To avoid this answer being the length of a thesis, I have added comments in all codes to help you understand what each function does and I highly recommend that you read and thoroughly understand them.

Firstly, in your theme folder, add a folder named `admin` and inside it, create file `class.new_tinymce_btn.php` with code:

```
<?php
//wpex_37798_christine_cooper
//class start
class add_new_tinymce_btn {

public $btn_arr;
public $js_file;
/*
 * call the constructor and set class variables
 * From the constructor call the functions via wordpress action/filter
*/
function __construct($seperator, $btn_name,$javascrip_location){
  $this->btn_arr = array("Seperator"=>$seperator,"Name"=>$btn_name);
  $this->js_file = $javascrip_location;
  add_action('init', array(&$this,'add_tinymce_button'));
  add_filter( 'tiny_mce_version', array(&$this,'refresh_mce_version'));

}
/*
 * create the buttons only if the user has editing privs.
 * If so we create the button and add it to the tinymce button array
*/
function add_tinymce_button() {
   if ( ! current_user_can('edit_posts') && ! current_user_can('edit_pages') )
     return;
   if ( get_user_option('rich_editing') == 'true') {
     //the function that adds the javascript
     add_filter('mce_external_plugins', array(&$this,'add_new_tinymce_plugin'));
     //adds the button to the tinymce button array
     add_filter('mce_buttons', array(&$this,'register_new_button')); 
   }
}
/*
 * add the new button to the tinymce array
*/
function register_new_button($buttons) {
   array_push($buttons, $this->btn_arr["Seperator"],$this->btn_arr["Name"]);
   return $buttons;
}
/*
 * Call the javascript file that loads the 
 * instructions for the new button
*/
function add_new_tinymce_plugin($plugin_array) {
   $plugin_array[$this->btn_arr['Name']] = $this->js_file;
   return $plugin_array;
}
/*
 * This function tricks tinymce in thinking 
 * it needs to refresh the buttons
*/
function refresh_mce_version($ver) {
  $ver += 3;
  return $ver;
}

}//class end
?>
```

This code will add custom buttons to the visual editor.

Next, in your theme folder, create these folders `adminjs/buttons` and inside, create this JS file `spacebutton.js` with code:

```
(function() {
    tinymce.create('tinymce.plugins.nextpage', {
        init : function(ed, url) {
            ed.addButton('nextpage', {
                title : 'Space Button',
                image : url+'/images/btn_spacebutton.png',
                onclick : function() {                    
                    var prompt_text = "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;";
                    var caret = "caret_pos_holder";
                    var insert = "<p>" + prompt_text + " &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</p> <span id="+caret+"></span>";
                     ed.execCommand('mceInsertContent', false, insert);
                     ed.selection.select(ed.dom.select('span#caret_pos_holder')[0]); //select the span
                     ed.dom.remove(ed.dom.select('span#caret_pos_holder')[0]); //remove the span
                }
            });
        },
        createControl : function(n, cm) {
            return null;
        },
    });
    tinymce.PluginManager.add('nextpage', tinymce.plugins.nextpage);
})();
```

You will need to add an image for the button (`/images/btn_spacebutton.png`). The above code is a rather simple javascript function for what happens when the button is pressed.

Now you will need to load this button class by adding this to your functions file:

```
//load custom buttons class
require_once (TEMPLATEPATH . '/admin/class.new_tinymce_btn.php');
//create an instance of the class
$t = new add_new_tinymce_btn('|','nextpage',get_bloginfo('template_url').'/adminjs/buttons/spacebutton.js');
```

That is it. You should find your new custom button in the visual editor. Whenever you want to add more custom buttons, just add a new JS file with the button function and load the button class as demonstrated above.

Answer (score 5):

TL;DR, code is at the bottom.

OK, this should work for you, but it is a beta. It works for me, but I haven't done any kind of rigorous testing. One thing, it doesn't output four consecutive `&nbsp;` entities; it does a stuttered `&nbsp;` `[space]` `&nbsp;` `[space]`, but at least it keeps them as-is when switching back-and-forth between Visual & Text modes.  It only works in Visual mode, I haven't taken the time to figure out how to make it work in Text mode.

It comes in two files, name as you see fit. I used the <strike>highly imaginative</strike> name: *4Spaces*. :) The TinyMCE button is on the top-row, far-right, of the editor. It'll show whatever your flavor of browser shows for non-existent images. That's easily changed in *4spaces.js*, line 8:

```
image   : url + '/' + 'YOUR_IMAGE_HERE.png'
```

Change `YOUR_IMAGE_HERE.png' to your image file, relative to the two files, or use an absolute URI like so:

```
image   : '/path/to/image/YOUR_IMAGE_HERE.png'
```

or

```
image   : 'http://example.com/path/to/image/YOUR_IMAGE_HERE.png'
```

I've commented and/or left some existing comments throughout the PHP, the JavaScript comments are sparse. You'll see in the PHP header section where the PHP code came from and *kind of* where the JavaScript originated.

Two notable credits, both listed in the PHP header: [this WordPress.SE Answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/54398/how-can-i-stop-tinymce-from-converting-my-html-entities-to-characters#answer-54480) that provided the code that stops TinyMCE (or WordPress, not sure which) from stripping out the spaces, and the link provided in the prior answer by @Alexey, which, while not critical, helped me stumble onto the JS solution.

I couldn't make the code in [that link](http://brettterpstra.com/adding-a-tinymce-button/) work, but eventually came back to it and found the nugget that brought it all together (with some tweaking, to be sure).

I think that about sums everything up. Here's the code:

#### 4spaces.php

```
<?php
/* Plugin Name: 4Spaces
 * Version: 0.1.0
 * Author: AK Ted
 * Author URI: http://akted.com
 * License: GPLv2 or later
 *
 *
 * PHP code adapted & refined from the following two sources:
 * WordPress Codex - http://codex.wordpress.org/TinyMCE_Custom_Buttons#Loading_a_TinyMCE__Plugin
 *
 * WordPress Answers (Stack Exchange) - https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/54398/how-can-i-stop-tinymce-from-converting-my-html-entities-to-characters#answer-54480
 *
 *
 * The JavaScript arose from a lot of trial-and-error, with code [beat into submission...er, I mean] inspired by both of the following sources:
 * tinymce wiki - http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Creating_a_plugin
 * &
 * brett terpstra - http://brettterpstra.com/2010/04/17/adding-a-tinymce-button/
 *
 */

new akt_4spaces();

class akt_4spaces {
    function __construct() {
        add_action('admin_init', array($this, 'init'));
    } // function __construct

    // callback for init
    // sets all the hooks only if user has capability & rich_editing is true 
    function init() {
        // Don't bother doing this stuff if the current user lacks permissions
        if ( ! current_user_can('edit_posts') && ! current_user_can('edit_pages') ) {
            return;
        }

       // Add only in Rich Editor mode
       if ( get_user_option('rich_editing') == 'true') {
            add_filter('mce_buttons', array($this, 'add_button'));
            add_filter('mce_external_plugins', array($this, 'add_tinymce_plugin'));
            add_filter('tiny_mce_before_init', array($this, 'preserve_entities'));
       }
    } // function init


    // callback for mce_buttons filter
    // adds button to TinyMCE
    function add_button($buttons) {
        array_push($buttons, 'separator', 'four_spaces');
        return $buttons;
    } // function add_button

    // callback for mce_external_plugins filter
    // attaches the JavaScript file to TinyMCE
    function add_tinymce_plugin($plugin_array) {
        $plugin_array['four_spaces'] = plugins_url('/', __FILE__) . '4spaces.js';
        return $plugin_array;
    } // function add_tinymce_plugin


    // callback for tiny_mce_before_init
    // stops TinyMCE (WordPress?) from automatically converting &nbsp; entities
    function preserve_entities( $initArray ) {
        // The odd entries are the entity *number*, the even entries are the entity *name*. If the entity has no name,
        // use the number, prefixed with a hash (for example, the service mark is "8480,#8480").
        $initArray['entities'] = '160,nbsp,' . $initArray['entities'];
        return $initArray;
    } // function preserve_entities

} // class akt_4spaces
```

#### 4spaces.js

```
(function() {

    tinymce.create('tinymce.plugins.four_spaces', {
        init : function(ed, url) {
            // Register four_spaces button
            ed.addButton('four_spaces', {
                title   : '4Spaces',
                image   : url + '/' + 'YOUR_IMAGE_HERE.png',
                onclick : function() {
                    ed.execCommand(
                        "mceInsertContent",
                        false,
                        "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;"
                    );
                }
            });
        }
    });

    // Register plugin
    tinymce.PluginManager.add('four_spaces', tinymce.plugins.four_spaces);

})();
```

Edit: I forgot to mention, for those who don't know, put both of those files into a directory under `/wp-content/plugins/` (default path). It should look something like
    /wp-content/plugins/4spaces/
or whatever name you decide to call it, then activate it in Admin.

P.S. - I'm relatively new to *OOP*, so welcome any and all criticisms, advice, etc., from anyone viewing this answer.

Comment: As it runs only in admin, instead of the `init` hook, `admin_init`. Maybe simply `if ( get_user_option('rich_editing') ) {/*etc*/}`. For the image, [`wp_localize_script`](http://pippinsplugins.com/use-wp_localize_script-it-is-awesome/), so you feed the image to JS through PHP. As final touch, a [wiki image](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/6/67/WikEd_logo.png), so the icon works out of the box. +1 Nice write-up :)

Comment: Thanks, @brasofilo! I'd heard of wp_localize_script but hadn't yet tried understanding anything about it. Your [link](http://pippinsplugins.com/use-wp_localize_script-it-is-awesome/) was awesome! Very simply explained. And I've fixed the init. I can't *believe* I missed that one!

Comment: And re: 'rich_editing', that's a good idea, but I might leave it in for reference. It makes it obvious that it should only work if you have enough *juice*, i.e., an editor or administrator. But for a production plugin I would definitely remove it. Thanks for the critique! :)

Comment: The localize trick is really cool and easy, I believe this is the [origin of the trickery](http://ottopress.com/tag/wp_localize_script/). Don't worry, with massive daily doses of code, I think one can miss many things :P