# TinyMCE HTML Encode Backslash

Tags: tinymce, encoding

so my question is similar to the one found [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/54398/how-can-i-stop-tinymce-from-converting-my-html-entities-to-characters?newreg=a76d1ec92cba4bc5b83a56d16b3e2768), following the example there i am trying to force Tiny MCE to encode backslashes......

currently all i am doing to test this is setting a break point on the page for the following line

```
tinymce.init( init );
```

then i run the following in the console

```
init.entities += ",92,#92"; init.entity_encoding = "named";
```

I see the values update in the init object but my \ is not converted....

not really sure what i am missing......

Answer (score 0):

ok so finally found a solution to this. i had to edit class-wp-editor.php and include the following for the $first_init array

```
                'setup' => 'function(ed) 
                {                        
                    ed.onGetContent.add(function(ed, o) {
                        // Replaces all a characters with b characters
                        o.content = o.content.replace(/\\\\/g, "&#92;");
                    });
                }',
```