# How can I stop a function from encoding an entity?

Tags: functions, wp-editor

I'm using the code below in my `functions.php` to pre-populate new posts.

It works fine, except if I use entities (example: `&raquo;`), which are converted (example: ») when I open the edit page for a new post.

I prefer to keep them unconverted.

```
add_filter( 'default_content', 'pu_default_editor_content' );

function pu_default_editor_content( $content ) {
  global $post_type;
  switch( $post_type ) {
    case 'post':
      $content = 'Default content for blog posts.';
    break;
  }
  return $content;
}
```

Comment: Any reason why you can't use the text tab in the editor?

Comment: @Andy Macaulay-Brook... not sure what you mean.

Comment: I read your question as saying that you don't like seeing the conversion in the visual editor so I though maybe switching to the text tab there would be easier than coding something, or have I misunderstood?

Comment: @Andy Macaulay-Brook... ah, understood. For years, I've disabled the visual editor.

Answer (score 1):

### Default Editor Content

Here is an updated version of the `pu_default_editor_content()` function which will take into account for when a user has disabled the Visual Editor (per your comment).

```
function pu_default_editor_content( $content ) {
    global $post_type;

    switch( $post_type ) {
        case 'post' :
            $content = 'Default content for blog posts. &raquo; &raquo; &raquo;';
            $rich_editing = get_user_option( 'rich_editing', get_current_user_id() );

            if ( 'false' === $rich_editing ) {
                $content = htmlspecialchars( $content );
            }   
        break;
    }

    return $content;
}
add_filter( 'default_content', 'pu_default_editor_content' );
```

### Rich Text Editor Disabled view

[image: editor-default-content-rich-text-disabled]
User has *Visual Editor* **disabled** under *User > Profile*.

### TinyMCE/QuickTags

If the Visual Editor is enabled, which is the default setup, TinyMCE will need to be configured to show named entities. Encoding is being applied by TinyMCE, but this behavior can be customized via the `tiny_mce_before_init` hook. [Thanks to this answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/54398/how-can-i-stop-tinymce-from-converting-my-html-entities-to-characters) for the tip.

Add additional entities that you may need to the `$settings['entities']` string. Documentation on formatting is [here](https://www.tinymce.com/docs/configure/content-filtering/#entities):

> This option contains a comma separated list of entity names that is
>   used instead of characters. Odd items are the character code and even
>   items are the name of the character code.

```
// Custom configuration for TinyMCE
function wpse241282_tiny_mce_before_init( $settings, $editor_id ) {

    // Used named encodings (the default setting in WordPress is raw).
    // https://www.tinymce.com/docs/configure/content-filtering/#encodingtypes
    $settings['entity_encoding'] = 'named';

    // Default entities for TinyMCE: 38,amp,60,lt,62,gt1
    // Additional entities: copy, reg, trade, service mark, euro, right angle quote, left angle quote
    // The odd entires are the entity *number*, the even entries are the entity *name*. If the entity has no name,
    // use the number, prefixed with a hash (for example, the service mark is "8480,#8480").

    $entities = '169,copy,174,reg,8482,trade,8480,#8480,8364,euro,187,raquo,171,laquo';

    if ( isset( $settings['entities'] ) && ! empty( $settings['entities'] ) ) {
        $settings['entities'] .= ',' . $entities;
    } else {
        $settings['entities'] = $entities;
    }
    return $settings;
}
add_filter( 'tiny_mce_before_init', 'wpse241282_tiny_mce_before_init', 10, 2 );
add_filter( 'quicktags_settings', 'wpse241282_tiny_mce_before_init', 10, 2 );
```

### Visual Editor Enabled

[image]
User has *Visual Editor* **enabled** under *User > Profile*.

Comment: thanks. But I have the visual editor disabled, so does TinyMCE still become involved? The suggested code doesn't change things.

Comment: Okay, that's an important detail it turns out. I've updated the answer and have tested the code for when user's have disabled the visual editor.

Comment: thanks, appreciated. But it seems to be of no effect, the new post is populated with » rather than &raquo;.

Comment: All good. I tried, and it's working for me, for whatever that's worth :-) Added some images to illustrate what I'm seeing.

Comment: Thanks, again. ;-) I'll investigate my code to sort this.

Comment: Not tech-minded, I don't pretend to understand much of this. And htmlspecialchars is new to me... but if I use '&amp;raquo;' in either my original or your code, the post is populated with &raquo; - which is the result I want. I'm wondering if this behavior offers a clue to what I need to fix with my install so your example works.

Comment: Seems like there may code altering the behavior of things via a theme or plugin. Try disabling all plugins and switching to an unmodified default WordPress theme.